# Cassandra java client

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I would like to use cassandra for my use case and searching java client for it. I found many java interfaces for cassandra along with Spring data cassandra. I have been using spring from many years. I would like to know spring data cassandra vs Astyanax in terms of performance and features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When choosing a Cassandra driver, one of the more important aspects to consider is which protocol it uses at its core.  Astyanax uses Thrift, and Spring uses the new CQL3 binary protocol.

Why is this important?

Cassandra 2.1 brought some significant performance gains in terms of the [CQL3/binary protocol vs. the original Thrift protocol](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-2-1-now-over-50-faster).  I have used Astyanax before (2 years ago), and at the time it had some significant improvements over Hector.  But the newer CQL3-based drivers are much easier to use.  And now that they also out-perform the Thrift-based drivers, the choice has become much easier.

So given the choice between Astyanax and Spring, I would choose Spring.

Honestly though, if you are starting a new project you should consider the [DataStax Java Driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/common/drivers/introduction/introArchOverview_c.html).  It is also CQL3/binary based, and the latest version has some usability improvements like an [Object-mapping API](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html) that greatly simplifies basic CRUD operations.  And you simply cannot go wrong by using a [DataStax supported driver](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [CassandraExecutor](https://cdn.rawgit.com/landawn/AbacusUtil/master/docs/CassandraExecutor_view.html), a simple wrapper based on [DataStax Java Driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.2/java-driver/whatsNew2.html). Comparing to the Java Driver, CassandraExecutor has below features:

- Consistent/Integrated/concise APIs for (sync/Async) operations(CRUD) with SQL/entity.
- [DataSet](https://cdn.rawgit.com/landawn/AbacusUtil/master/docs/DataSet_view.html), which supports distinct/merge/sort/groupBy/join/union/unionAll/except/intersect/paginate/filter/count/toJOSN/toXML/toCVS...

Here is a simple CRUD(create/read/update/delete) sample:

```
Account account = createAccount();
// create
String sql_insert = NE.insert(ID, GUI, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME).into(Account.class).sql();
cassandraExecutor.execute(sql_insert, account);

// read
String sql_selectByGUI = NE.select(ID, GUI, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).from(Account._).where(L.eq(ID, L.QME)).sql();
Account dbAccount = cassandraExecutor.queryForEntity(Account.class, sql_selectByGUI, account);

// update
String sql_updateByLastName = NE.update(Account.class).set(FIRST_NAME).where(L.eq(ID, L.QME)).sql();

dbAccount.setFirstName("newFirstName");
cassandraExecutor.execute(sql_updateByLastName, dbAccount);

// delete
String sql_deleteByFirstName = NE.deleteFrom(Account.class).where(L.eq(ID, L.QME)).sql();
cassandraExecutor.execute(sql_deleteByFirstName, dbAccount);
```

(Declaration：I'm the developer of CassandraExecutor)